# Kendo Hierarchy Grid - Hierarchy does not work

Tags: c#, mvvm, kendo-ui

I am trying to create a hierarchical grid in mvvm, went through multiple examples, but no luck. Must have been doing some mistake. Although it is not giving any exception, but Hierarchy is not working, normal grid is getting populated.

My VM is as follows:

```js
var PolicyList;
xxx.PayRollProcess.PayRollPolicy = (function ($, kendo, _, App) {

  var vmSalaryPolicy = kendo.observable({
    // Properties
    //*******************************
    Id: null,
    Name: null,
    Description: null,
    CreatedBy: null,
    CreatedDate: null,
    PolicyID: null,
    SaveFieldButtonText: "Save Field",
    PolicyList : new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
        read: {
          type: "GET",
          url: xxx.Layout.viewModel.GetApiUrl("PayRoll/GetPolicies"),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          complete: function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data.responseJSON !== null) {
              vmSalaryPolicy.set("IsRecordFound", data.responseJSON.length > 0 ? true : false);
              vmSalaryPolicy.set("SalryField", data.responseJSON[0]);
            }
          },
          error: function (err) {
            xxx.Layout.viewModel.ShowError(err);
          }
        }
      },
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            SalaryPolicyID: { type: "number" },
            Name: { type: "string" },
            Description: { type: "string" },
            CreatedBy: { type: "bool" },
            CreatedOn: { type: "string" }
          }
        }
      },
      pageSize: 10
    }),
    AllPolicyFieldDetailList : new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
        read: {
          type: "GET",
          url: xxx.Layout.viewModel.GetApiUrl("PayRoll/GetAllPayRollPolicyDetails"),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          complete: function (data) {
            if (data.responseJSON !== null) {
              vmSalaryField.set("IsRecordFound", data.responseJSON.length > 0 ? true : false);
              vmSalaryField.set("SalryField", data.responseJSON[0]);
            }
          },
          error: function (err) {
            xxx.Layout.viewModel.ShowError(err);
          }
        }
      },
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            SalaryPolicyID: { type: "number" },
            SalaryPolicyName: { type: "bool" },
            SalaryPolicyDescription: { type: "string" },
            SalaryFieldID: { type: "string" },
            SalaryFieldName: { type: "bool" },
            Type: { type: "bool" },
            HeaderName: { type: "string" }
          }
        }
      },
      pageSize: 10
    }),
    dataSource: PolicyList,
    detailInit: function (e) {
      debugger;
      $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
          type: "Get",
          transport: {
            read: {
              type: "GET",
              url: xxx.Layout.viewModel.GetApiUrl("PayRoll/GetAllPayRollPolicyDetails"),
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              complete: function (data) {
                if (data.responseJSON !== null) {
                  vmSalaryPolicy.set("IsRecordFound", data.responseJSON.length > 0 ? true : false);
                  vmSalaryPolicy.set("SalryField", data.responseJSON[0]);
                }
              },
              error: function (err) {
                xxx.Layout.viewModel.ShowError(err);
              }
            }
          },
          serverPaging: true,
          serverSorting: true,
          serverFiltering: true,
          pageSize: 6,
          filter: { field: "SalaryPolicyID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.SalaryPolicyID }
        },
        scrollable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
          { field: "SalaryFieldID", title: "ID", width: "110px" },
          { field: "SalaryFieldName", title: "Field Name", width: "110px" },
          { field: "Type", title: "Type" },
          { field: "HeaderName", title: "Header Name", width: "300px" }
        ]
      });
    },
    dataBound: function (e) {
      debugger;
      e.sender.expandRow(e.sender.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    },
  });

  $(function () {
    kendo.bind($("#PolicyPage"), vmSalaryPolicy);
  });
  return { viewModel: vmSalaryPolicy };
})(jQuery, kendo, _, xxx);
```

.cshtml contains:

```
<div class="box-body rm-padding">
  <div data-bind="invisible: IsRecordFound">No Policy Details found.</div>
  <div id="PayRollPolicyFieldGrid"
       data-role="grid"
       data-sortable="true"
       data-pageable="true"
       data-height="450"
       data-detail-init="detailInit"
       data-columns='[{"field": "SalaryPolicyID"}, {"field": "Name"}, {"field": "Description"}, {"field": "CreatedBy"}, {"field": "CreatedOn"}]'
       data-bind="source: PolicyList, events: { dataBound: dataBound }">
  </div>

</div>
```

I tried the example [here](https://jsbin.com/egeviw/2/edit?html,output)

But no luck.

It loads only the grid with Policy details.

The JSON for GetPolicies:

```
{
  "ArrayOfSalaryPolicy": {
  "SalaryPolicy": {
    "CreatedBy": "101429",
      "CreatedOn": "2019-01-18T21:01:21.97",
      "Description": "Band A Salary Policy",
      "Name": "Band-A",
      "SalaryPolicyID": "1"
  },
  "_xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "_xmlns": "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xxx.Common"
}
}
```

The JSON for the AllPolicyFieldDetailList:

```
{
  "ArrayOfSalaryPolicyField": {
  "SalaryPolicyField": [
    {

      "HeaderID": "0",
      "HeaderName": "OtherDeduction",
      "ID": "5",
      "IsActive": "false",
      "SalaryFieldID": "0",
      "SalaryFieldName": "LWF",
      "SalaryPolicyDescription": "Band A Salary Policy",
      "SalaryPolicyID": "1",
      "SalaryPolicyName": "Band-A",
      "Type": "Deduction"
    },
    {

      "HeaderID": "0",
      "HeaderName": "StatutoryDeduction",
      "ID": "3",
      "IsActive": "false",
      "SalaryFieldID": "0",
      "SalaryFieldName": "PF",
      "SalaryPolicyDescription": "Band A Salary Policy",
      "SalaryPolicyID": "1",
      "SalaryPolicyName": "Band-A",
      "Type": "Deduction"
    },
    {

      "HeaderID": "0",
      "HeaderName": "StatutoryDeduction",
      "ID": "4",
      "IsActive": "false",
      "SalaryFieldID": "0",
      "SalaryFieldName": "TDS",
      "SalaryPolicyDescription": "Band A Salary Policy",
      "SalaryPolicyID": "1",
      "SalaryPolicyName": "Band-A",
      "Type": "Deduction"
    },
    {

      "HeaderID": "0",
      "HeaderName": "Other Allwances",
      "ID": "2",
      "IsActive": "false",
      "SalaryFieldID": "0",
      "SalaryFieldName": "Conveyance",
      "SalaryPolicyDescription": "Band A Salary Policy",
      "SalaryPolicyID": "1",
      "SalaryPolicyName": "Band-A",
      "Type": "Earning"
    },
    {

      "HeaderID": "0",
      "HeaderName": "Earnings",
      "ID": "1",
      "IsActive": "false",
      "SalaryFieldID": "0",
      "SalaryFieldName": "HRA",
      "SalaryPolicyDescription": "Band A Salary Policy",
      "SalaryPolicyID": "1",
      "SalaryPolicyName": "Band-A",
      "Type": "Earning"
    }
  ],
    "_xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "_xmlns": "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xxx.Common"
}}
```

I compared the examples provided with my code at runtime, an interesting finding is, in examples, it loads the "k-master-row" class in `<tr>` but in my case it does not.

The code runs without any exception and it loads the policies. But it does not show the hierarchy grid.
I had put the "debugger" in dataInit, but it never goes there or stops.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to get master-detail grid working using MVVM was to supply a template for the detail row (even if it's just an 'empty' one, which you later manipulate during the `detailInit` event).

Also note, during MVVM widget initialization the context is the window hence when your `data-detail-init` attribute is parsed, kendo will look in the wrong place. You should move that to the binding/events attribute, since when the bindings are set up the context is the observable to which you are binding. I've modified your markup to demonstrate this.

```
<script id="grid-detail-placeholder" type="text/x-kendo-template"></script>

<div class="box-body rm-padding">
  <div data-bind="invisible: IsRecordFound">No Policy Details found.</div>
  <div id="PayRollPolicyFieldGrid"
       data-role="grid"
       data-sortable="true"
       data-pageable="true"
       data-height="450"
       data-detail-template="grid-detail-placeholder"
       data-columns='[{"field": "SalaryPolicyID"}, {"field": "Name"}, {"field": "Description"}, {"field": "CreatedBy"}, {"field": "CreatedOn"}]'
       data-bind="source: PolicyList, events: { detailInit: detailInit, dataBound: dataBound }">
  </div>

</div>
```